# Move File From one location to other in C#

Tags: c#, file-io

I am using the following code to move a file from one location to another in a loop, while I am creating a new file every time in the loop, but the following exception is thrown:

```
System.IO.IOException: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileInfo.MoveTo(String destFileName).
```

This is my code:

```
string strFile = strFileName;

try
{
    string strFinalPath = ApplicationConfiguration.FinalInvoiceFolder;
    if (!Directory.Exists(strFinalPath))
    {    
        Directory.CreateDirectory(strFinalPath);
    }

    if (File.Exists(strPrintedFilePath))
    {    
        objFile.MoveTo(strFinalPath + strFile);    
    }   
}
catch (Exception ex2)
{
    WriteLogCustom(ex2.ToString() + ex2.InnerException.ToString(), true);
}
```

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/file-move

Comment: To combine 2 or more string to a path better you Path.Combine(strFinalPath, strFile)

Comment: Which are the filename of your files?

Comment: use `Path` class to play with Paths. It is available in `System.IO`

Comment: The reason could be, you could have tried to move the file mentioned in `objFile` to the mentioned location

Comment: It looks like the destination already exists and the move cannot be performed. Have you tried first deleting the destination if already exists and then moving?

Comment: You dont show where `strFileName` comes from, if you want to create unique file names, this is the important bit. I imagine that the same `strFileName` value is used across iterations.

Answer (score 3):

Your code should look something like this

```
if (File.Exists(strPrintedFilePath))
{    
    string destinationPath = Path.Combine(strFinalPath, strFile);
    if(File.Exists(destinationPath)
    {   
        // your logic to handle situations
        // when a destination file already exists
    }
    else  
    {            
        objFile.MoveTo(destinationPath);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya agery with your code, but how can it possible, file should not be there, because i am creating pdf file in loop with using time and seconds in file naming, so at the of moving, how can same file exist in target folder, If i will use this. some file has been remained in source folder.

Comment: You can tweak this code, if you remove the `else` keyword, then the files will be moved anyway. I suspect, if you run the same code several times, the files that you already moved will cause conflicts. Unless you generate a unique name per each run.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string path1 = @"C:\Users\username\Desktop\Erro1.png";

string path2 = @"C:\test\Erro1.png";

if (File.Exists(path2))
    File.Delete(path2);

// Move the file.
File.Move(path1, path2);
```

make sure that Your destination path has a full rights permission otherwise it gives you access denied error.

Comment: is that the exception that is thrown?

Comment: Yes exception occurs if your destination path has not enough rights.

Comment: But, not with the `Message` in the question.

Comment: No error is not showing every time, suppose i have 10000 files then all files sucessfully moved but 200 files has been remain to move, So rights problem can't possible.

Comment: I suggest you to create a folder on your local machine and remove rights of that and then check what happen. @HemantSoni

Comment: How can It logically possible, If folder does not have rights. single file should not be moved. but code have moved some files but some remain.

Comment: that file may be open OR access by other user that's why it may not moved.
put try/catch and get what exact error comes. @HemantSoni

Comment: I am using windows service for this. and we picked some records from DB and create PDF for these records. first create pdf in temp folder and write invoice for these records in this pdf. then after write all invoices, we move all pdf into target folder. and pdf name is generated in loop at the of creation. when filrst file is moved then second files is created so how can file is generated with same name.and bwfore move I have closed that file. And this service is runing only from single computer

Comment: Error is System.IO.IOException: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileInfo.MoveTo(String destFileName)

Comment: I update my answer that if file is already exists on destination path then first delete from there and then move.
it might be good practise. @HemantSoni